# Missing required parameter for [Route: BatterFirst.update] [URI: BatterFirst/{BatterFirst}] [Missing parameter: BatterFirst]. edit.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

While I am doing laravel CRUD project I got . I stuck here its 2 days

Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: BatterFirst.update] [URI: BatterFirst/{BatterFirst}] [Missing parameter: BatterFirst]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CricBangla\resources\views\BatterFirst\edit.blade.php) Error.

I can`t find whire is the error.

Here is my web.php

```
Route::resource('BatterFirst', BatterFirstController::class);
```

This is my model BatterFirst.php

```
class BatterFirst extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'batterfirst';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'runs', 'balls', 'sixs', 'fours'
    ];
}
```

This is my BatterFirstController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\BatterFirst;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BatterFirstController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = BatterFirst::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('BatterFirst.index',compact('data'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('BatterFirst.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'runs' => 'required',
            'balls' => 'required',
            'sixs' => 'required',
            'fours' => 'required',
        ]);

        BatterFirst::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('BatterFirst.index')
                        ->with('success','Batter created successfully.');
    }

    public function show(BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        return view('BatterFirst.show',compact('batterFirst'));
    }

    public function edit(BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        return view('BatterFirst.edit',compact('batterFirst'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'runs' => 'required',
            'balls' => 'required',
            'sixs' => 'required',
            'fours' => 'required',
        ]);

        $batterFirst->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('BatterFirst.index')
                        ->with('success','Batter updated successfully');
    }

    public function destroy(BatterFirst $batterFirst)
    {
        $batterFirst->delete();

        return redirect()->route('BatterFirst.index')
                        ->with('success','Batter deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

This is my edit.blade.php

```
@extends('BatterFirst.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Edit Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.index') }}"> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{{ route('BatterFirst.update',$batterFirst->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Name:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $batterFirst->name }}" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Runs:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="runs" value="{{ $batterFirst->runs }}" class="form-control" placeholder="runs">                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Balls:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="balls" value="{{ $batterFirst->balls }}" class="form-control" placeholder="balls">                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Sixs:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="sixs" value="{{ $batterFirst->runs }}" class="form-control" placeholder="sixs">                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Fours:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="fours" value="{{ $batterFirst->fours }}" class="form-control" placeholder="fours">                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
@endsection
```

[In this image when i click delete button it showing Batter delete successfully but not deleting Batter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byWPa.png)

This is my index.blade.php

```
@extends('BatterFirst.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5rem;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD Example from scratch - laravelcode.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.create') }}"> Create New Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Runs</th>
            <th>Balls</th>
            <th>Sixs</th>
            <th>Fours</th>
            <th>Strick Rate</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->runs }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->balls }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->sixs }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->fours }}</td>
            {{-- <td>{{ $value->runs/$value->balls*100 }}</td> --}}
            <td>@if ($value->runs > 0 and $value->runs ==0)
                    {{ $value->runs*100 }}
                @elseif ($value->balls>0 and $value->runs ==0)
                    {{ $value->balls*$value->runs }}
                @elseif ($value->balls==0 and $value->runs ==0)
                    {{ $value->balls *  $value->runs }}
                @elseif ($value->runs>0 and $value->balls>=0)
                    {{ $value->runs/$value->balls*100 }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('BatterFirst.destroy',$value->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.show',$value->id) }}">Show</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('BatterFirst.edit',$value->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {!! $data->links() !!}
@endsection
```

Note: I just started learning laravel. Thanks

Comment: I did not see something that looks wrong on a first glance - However, I personally typically don't use the route helper... can you maybe try `route('BatterFirst.update', ['BatterFirst' => $batterFirst->id])` ? So trying to pass the specific, requested parameter ?

Comment: Did you define the destroy route with an optional parameter? In that case you "create" an empty model, that you "delete" (not in the db, in your code) and you get no error. You need to specify what parameter you pass like @Frnak commented `['BatterFirst' => $batterFirst->id]` .

Comment: @Frnak its not working

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens CZ of wrong naming of table and model, folders

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the method POST. Update will use PUT as Method.

```
  <form action="{{ route('BatterFirst.update',$batterFirst->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
```

and then change inside your route function this. Pass the id inside a array.

```
"{{route('BatterFirst.update',['id' => $batterFirst->id])}}"
```

then will ĺooking so:

```
  <form action="{{ route('BatterFirst.update',['id' => $batterFirst->id]) }}" method="PUT">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
```

Comment: Did you say something like that <form action="{{route('BatterFirst.update',['id' => $batterFirst->id])}}" method="PUT"> I tried it but not working

Comment: @ShahedKhan You got an error message?

Comment: I got same error